# RetroPie no HDMI output and "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer"

Tags: sd-card, hdmi, output, retropie

I'm trying to install RetroPie onto my RP, it already worked with the OS it came with before trying this.

I formatted the SD card altogether first and then after expanding the disk image using `dd` to put RetroPie (v2.3) onto my SD card, I plug it into my TV's HDMI and nothing happens and when I plug the SD card back into my laptop (Mac 10.9) I get this message "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer".

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I've been following this guide:

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-retro-game-console-498561192

And haven't gotten passed step one.

Anyone having similar issues?

Comment: Have you tried a different card, and a fresh image.

Answer (score 2):

I followed this guide instead and it worked wonders!

http://supernintendopi.wordpress.com/

(This was a link at the bottom of the LifeHacker website you provided)

Format not only the flash drive on your Mac, but write the image to the SD card. **You need to write the image you downloaded to the SD card.** This guide shows you what you need to use if using a Mac computer:
http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Flashing_the_SD_card_using_Mac_OSX

I don't know if you flashed the image to the SD card or not, but that is definitely where I would start.

Answer (score 1):

The SD card you've imaged is in Linux format. It is not designed to be readable by your Mac.